# MFA status for azure AD users using dotnet sdk

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I was looking for the dotnet sdk method to get the azure active directory user's MFA status. As far as I know, it is available in beta version of Micorsoft Graph(credentialUserRegistrationDetails), but using that version for production application is not recommended, so is there any other dotnet sdk method available ?

Also want to confirm, This 'credentialUserRegistrationDetails' method from beta version to work it properly should we need B2C tenant or Premium license of Azure AD? Cant It worked with non premium license azure tenant?

Comment: Hi, if the answer helps your problem, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as "accepted", thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I'm afraid that there isn't any other dotnet sdk for us to implement this requirement. The sdk in beta version request [microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-list-credentialuserregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) in backend, but it just exists beta graph api and not exists v1.0 graph api. So we can just use beta graph api or beta sdk.

Apart from this, here is another solution to get MFA status of users for your reference. But this solution is powershell command which may not help your needs.

```
Install-Module MSOnline

Connect-MsolService

Get-MsolUser -all | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{N="MFA Status"; E={ if( $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -ne $null){ $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State} else { "Disabled"}}}
```

For your second question, I think premium license is necessary because the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/authenticationmethods-usage-insights-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) shows us:

[image]